# jquery datepicker alert selected day formatted as 1 (or 2,...,14,...)

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How can I alert the selected day into a format like 1,2,3,4,...,31. I.E. 12.10.2009 should alert 12.

Comment: What exactly do you want? The numeric representation of the month?

Comment: you might wanna upvote and accept the answer, if you feel that my answer was good enough (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about a simple substring?

```
var day = dateFromDatePicker.substr(0, dateFromDatePicker.indexOf("."));
alert(day);
```

**edit:** my bad, you need to say from 0 to first index of "."

Comment: thx for feedback

function pickedDate(value, date, inst) { 
    var day = value.substr(value.indexOf("."));
    alert(day);
    }

alerts only:
.11.2009

The day is still missing.

Comment: thx a lot... works

meanwhile you gave me a kickstart with string manipulations:

var b = value;
var temp = new Array();
temp = b.split('.');
alert(temp[0]);

Comment: Yup, and that way might actually be better for you, in case you want to pull out month and year as well. You could simply do: `var month = temp[1]; var year = temp[2];`